# configure rdf database for spring web mvc application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, semantic-web, owl

What is the best solution to configure rdf/owl database for spring web mvc applications?
I am searching a solution to orm for owl in spring application.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [Stardog](http://docs.stardog.com/)? I'm not sure what your exact goal is with the database, but this is what I use for creating/accessing/querying/etc. triple stores programmatically. They have an API called SNARL - [here](https://gist.github.com/mhgrove/1045573) is a good example of how to use it with Java. They actually have a section in their docs for [Spring Programming](http://docs.stardog.com/#_spring_programming) and use some different beans. I use a combination of the spring programming (for querying) and the method in the first link (for setting up dbs and loading files).

Downside is OWL/XML and Owl Functional Syntax are not supported file formats, but you can just convert your file to RDF/XML (esp. easy if you're using Protege). If you're not using Protege, there are [other ways to do it](http://mowl-power.cs.man.ac.uk:8080/converter/).

If you have any further questions I'm happy to help out.

Comment: Thank you so much...Truley I don't know rdf and owl....I have an owl file and some queries for it to do some actions. and I have to write a web application with these queries...I am searching best solution to mapping java objects to this owl.

Comment: ...As i saw stardog documentation it supports owl.So Why do you say it does not support?

Comment: There's a difference between OWL, the language, and it's serialization formats such as OWL/XML and OWL Functional Syntax, neither of which are supported by Stardog. You can however use any RDF serialization, such as RDF/XML or Turtle, to load the ontology into Stardog